# Gatsby GraphQL for only current directory

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I followed the Gatsby tutorial and ended up with a GraphQL like:

```json
  query {
    allMdx(sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}) {
      nodes {
        frontmatter {
          date(formatString: "MMMM D, YYYY")
          title
        }
        id
        slug
      }
    }
  }
```

This gives me the expected result of:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "allMdx": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "date": "January 25, 2022",
            "title": "Image Blog"
          },
          "id": "cc11f4c4-43a5-573a-9ea6-3806f7e2fc64",
          "slug": "image-blog/"
        },
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "date": "July 24, 2021",
            "title": "Page B"
          },
          "id": "1fb36e34-d1f4-5ac2-8c18-1030733cfce1",
          "slug": "b"
        },
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "date": "July 24, 2021",
            "title": "Page C"
          },
          "id": "2f0ed709-c7ab-5a3f-9846-1340699b4bd1",
          "slug": "c"
        },
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "date": "July 24, 2021",
            "title": "Sub Page D"
          },
          "id": "d9cc842d-dc45-508a-8d5d-8dc1f2b0b232",
          "slug": "sub/d"
        },
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "date": "July 24, 2021",
            "title": "Sub Sub Page E"
          },
          "id": "2005bd62-37a7-580b-9950-e1b7c3688c0b",
          "slug": "sub/subsub/e"
        },
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "date": "July 23, 2021",
            "title": "Page A"
          },
          "id": "58dd9cf4-8e20-5602-87ef-5eb18cd74636",
          "slug": "a"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

As you can see the result contains all pages.

What I would like to achieve is to have an "index" page that only show links to the pages within the same directory of the "index" page.

How can I modify the query to return only the current directory's pages?

---

EDIT:

I made some progress by changing the query to:

```json
  query{
      allMdx(
        sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}
        filter: {slug: {regex: "/^sub/[^/]+$/"}}
      ) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "D MMMM YYYY")
            title
          }
          id
          slug
        }
      }
  }
```

which gives the result of:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "allMdx": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "date": "24 July 2021",
            "title": "Sub Page D"
          },
          "id": "4de57b7f-5e87-520f-ab06-940fb6f91340",
          "slug": "sub/d"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

But my graphQL is hard-coded. I still do not understand how to pass in a variable dynamically so that it would give different results depending on which slug/directory the page was loaded, for example to have something like:

```
filter: {slug: {regex: $expression}}
```

This is the full page code I have so far:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../../components/layout'

const BlogPage = ({ data, location }) => {
    //const slug = location.pathname;
    return (
        <Layout pageTitle="My Blog Posts">
            {
                data.allMdx.nodes.map(node => (
                    <article key={node.id}>
                        <h2>
                            <Link to={`/blog/${node.slug}`}>
                                {node.frontmatter.title}
                            </Link>
                        </h2>
                        <p>Posted: {node.frontmatter.date}</p>
                    </article>
                ))
            }
        </Layout>
    )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query{
      allMdx(
        sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}
        filter: {slug: {regex: "/^sub/[^/]+$/"}}
      ) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "D MMMM YYYY")
            title
          }
          id
          slug
        }
      }
  }
`

export default BlogPage
```

Comment: Which is the current directory? Where do you get that info?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I have updated the question. Assume this query is run from the "index" page. I suspect I should add some sort of filter on the parent id, or partial match on the path or something. I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fetching all data from the MDX (hence the `allMdx` node), set in the `gatsby-source-filesystem` so it's getting all `title` and `date` from `frontmatter`, without filtering.

One easy thing that is the straightforward workaround in this scenarios of filtering desired pages is adding a `key` field in your MDX files so you can filter your query using that field:

```
  query {
    allMdx(
    filter: {frontmatter: { key: { eq: "index-page"}}}
    sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}) {
      nodes {
        frontmatter {
          date(formatString: "MMMM D, YYYY")
          title
        }
        id
        slug
      }
    }
  }
```

So you will be only fetching one-page data.

Comment: Are there perhaps a way to filter according to the relative path so that I do not have to manually remember to add "keys" to the mdx files?

Comment: Sure, that's another way of doing this. Depending on the scenario, you can also use the `name` in the `gatsby-source-filesystem` (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/) which will stand for `sourceInstanceName` in GraphQL. In the end, the idea relies on getting some strong/unique field to filter your query in order to get only the requested data. Whatever you choose, you can reuse the query above changing the filter for your choice.